# Get text inside a anchor list element using jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="neither_nor_selector"  style="text-decoration: none;left: 18%;min-width: 65px;">
          <li><a title="neither">neither</a></li>
          <li><a title="nor">nor</a></li>
 </ul>
```

How to display the selected list item text

```
$("#neither_nor_selector option:selected").text()?
```

Comment: How do you know what is selected? Why not use <select>?

Comment: `option:selected` is for... [`option`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)s! But you are using a list with `li`s...

Comment: I have no idea what you are using for your dropdown menu (Bootstrap?) but try `.selected` or maybe `.active` if that doesn't work instead of `option:selected` in your jQuery selector.

Comment: @howderek I am using bootstrap

Comment: @ajmajmajma I dont want to use <option> and <select> because its changing the layout view. I want to use only <ul>

Comment: changing the layout view of options and select to mimic that of ul might be easier than reinventing options and selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this if you did not want to use a select.

```
   $(".dropdown-menu li").on("click", function(){
       //get the text here
       var myText = $(this).find("a").text();
       console.log(myText);
   });
```

This will just hook onto clicking any of the li's (i'm not sure what event your using to select so it could change i guess). and then you can do with it what you need.

Alternatively you could just re-style the select tag to look how you please (assuming you want a real dropdown here).

Example fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/v53aubL3/

Comment: Its displaying both the text "neithernor"

Comment: @budhavarapuranga works fine for me - posted fiddle too

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to anything and then give each element a different id:

```
 <li class="foo" id="first"><a title="neither">neither</a></li>
              <li class="foo" id="nor"><a title="nor">nor</a></li>
```

js:

```
$(".foo").click(function() {

var bar = $(this).attr('id');
alert(bar);
});
```